# Update UIlabel text from background Service

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uilabel

I have a method to make work in background method call.

in .h file:

```
@property (retain,nonatomic ) IBOutlet UILabel *progressLabel;
```

in .m file:

```
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
            // update UI on the main thread
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                 [self updateProgressView];
            });
        });

    }
```

and in `updateProgressView` is like:

```
-(void)updateProgressView{

     NSString *TxtProgress = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Processing %d/%d contacts",  self.processedContactNum, self.totalContactNum];
    NSLog(@"%@",TxtProgress);   
    [self.progressLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",TxtProgress]];
}
```

i am getting the Nslog Value but it is not shown in the UI.

any Help please ?

Comment: self.progressLabel is not 'nil', correct ?

Comment: self.progressLabel Nslog is:
<UILabel: 0x145567d0; frame = (40 220; 214 27); text = 'All Processed!'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x1455aac0>>

Comment: Any UI activities are supposed to happen on Main thread and not a good idea to ask Main thread to run async like this: dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(). dispatch_sync should work.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try following code

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(updateProgressView) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];

//instead of

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
                // update UI on the main thread
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                     [self updateProgressView];
                });
            });
```

Comment: Should not make any difference.

Comment: Than check your binding of IBOutlet UILabel *progressLabel; in story board or xib

Answer (score 1):

you can try following snippet to update your UI at any point. which works on MAIN Thread and used to update UI.

```
dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
     [self.progressLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",TxtProgress]];
});
```

Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

First instead of

```
[self.progressLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",TxtProgress]];
```

You can use

```
[self.progressLabel setText:TxtProgress];
```

Please check your IBOutlet is attached to UILabel in Xib file.

Otherwise everything fine, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I added a Nstimer by force to controll the process of time:

just add it:

```
            [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.01];
```

Thats it. Thanks to all.. 
:)